# Can descendants of the Prophet (syed) receive zakah?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, zakat, sayyid

Rasulullah said:

> Narrated Abu Huraira: Al-Hasan bin `Ali took a date from the dates
>   given in charity and put it in his mouth. The Prophet said, "Expel it
>   from your mouth. Don't you know that we do not eat a thing which is
>   given in charity?" ([Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/24#92) and [Muslim](http://sunnah.com/urn/223390))

This hadith clearly outlines the impermissibility of a "syed" person (someone proven to be from the lineage of rasulullah) receiving sadaqah from anyone else.

Is it permissible for them, then, to receive zakah?

---

Some groups and individuals believe other things about someone who is syed. That's fine, but don't answer this question with things like "syeds can take zakah" or "syeds can take zakah from syeds," or other beliefs. This is a clearly-stated axiom of my question.

Also, this question ignores the largely modern issue of *actually proving someone is syed.* Don't go there; that's a tangent, and something a lot of people claim to today. Again, the assumption is that you can or have verified that someone really IS syed.

Comment: I don't have the required reputation to edit the questions and create tags but it I think we should have tag for "Syed" and "Ahl-al-Bayt"

Comment: @AkramMellice "ahl al-bayt" is a loaded term which differs in definition of shia vs. sunni vs. others. I will create a "syed" tag though.

Comment: Might be you are right @ashes999, and here Syed tag can be more related ... Since (As much as I know), Shias commonly use saying Seyyed in these situations ... / Jazak Allah Khaira.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Members of Prophet's family such as the descendants of the family of Banu Hashim and Banu `Abdul-Muttalib (may Allah be pleased with them) cannot be paid zakah, because there are religious text showing that it is unlawful for them to take it.

A Hadith related by Imam Muslim (may Allah be merciful with him) on the authority of 'Abdul-Muttalib ibn Rabi`ah ibn Al-Harith (may Allah be pleased with him) who reported
that the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) said:

> Charity (Zakah) is not becoming for the family of Muhammad, as it is
>   people's impurities. **[Sahih Muslim, Book on Zakah, no.1072]**

In another narration:

> They (charities) are not permissible for Muhammad (peace be upon him),
>   nor for the family of Muhammad. **[Malik Muwatta']**

However, if the Zakah is given to some person other than members of the Prophet's family and then they give it as a gift to the members of the Prophet's family, that is permissible for them based on the following Hadith in which Um `Atiyyah (may Allah be pleased with her) said:

> The Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) sent me some lamb from the
>   Zakah. I sent `Aishah some of it. When the Messenger of Allah (peace
>   be upon him) came to Aishah, he asked, "Do you have anything (to
>   eat)?" She said, "Nothing, except the lamb that Nusaybah (Umm
>   'Atiyyah's nickname) sent us from that which you gave to her. He said,
>   "It has reached its proper place. **(Agreed upon by Al-Bukhari and Muslim and the version quoted is from Imam Muslim)**. In another Hadith reported on the authority of Barirah, the Prophet (peace be upon him) said:
>   It is charity for her, and a gift for us. **[Malik Muwatta']**

**Source:** [Giving Zakah to Al-ul-Bayt](http://www.alifta.com/Fatawa/fatawaDetails.aspx?View=Page&PageID=3478&PageNo=1&BookID=7)

Answer (score 1):

> Narated By Abu Huraira : Dates used to be brought to Allah's Apostle
>   immediately after being plucked. Different persons would bring their
>   dates till a big heap collected (in front of the Prophet). Once
>   Al-Hasan and Al-Husain were playing with these dates. One of them took
>   a date and put it in his mouth. Allah's Apostle looked at him and took
>   it out from his mouth and said, "Don't you know that Muhammad's
>   offspring do not eat what is given in charity?"
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhary, The Book of Obligatory Charity, Hadith Number:1509](http://www.hadithtranslations.com/ViewResultsFrame.aspx?sid=264424112&setID=1&bookID=24&hadithID=1509),
>   Narrated by: Abu-Huraira

From this *hadith* we can see that charity (i.e. *zakah* and *sadaqah*) is not to be taken by the prophet's family. Some scholars however *sadaqah nafilah* (non obligatory charity) with this. Other scholars (like Ibn Taimiyah) conclude that if the person (who is from Ahl Al Bait) is poor and is deserving of charity, then they may accept *zakah*.

Comment: I think Dr. Zakir Naik is of opinion that Prophet (P.B.U.H) forbid it 'at that time' because he didn't want people to confuse it as a compensation of his service to Islam. And now it is permissible because the confusion can't happen anymore also the tree is so large now that being a descendant isn't really relevant anymore. We're all descendants of Adam (P.B.U.h) too.

Comment: This is the same hadith I quoted. Do you have more links to scholarly statements about this interpretation? @HasanKhan please write your own answer in that case :)

Comment: @ashes999 that's all I have. Doesn't qualify for an answer http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FukPRQH-QCw

Comment: @HasanKhan I meant SystemDown.

Comment: @ashes999 - I'll see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

**According to [Jafari Fiqh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja'fari_jurisprudence):**

Sayyed can receive Sadaqah only from Sayyed. 
Also only Wajib Sadaqah like Zikat Fitrah and Zikat of property and Khums are banned to Sayyids. And they can receive Mustahab (recommended) Sadaqah.

> **Question :**
>
> Is it permissible for a "Sayyid" to have Sadaqa for their needs? If it
>   is permissible, then please specify the condition.
>
> **Answer :**
>
> It is permissible for a Hashimi to give his sadaqa to another Hashimi
>   or to a non-Hashimi. This includes both Zakat of property and zakat of
>   Fitra. But it is not permissible for a non-Hashimi to give his Sadaqa
>   to a Hashimi. If a Hashimi receives Zakat of property or fitra from a
>   non-Hashimi, it would be forbidden for him to use it, and he who gives
>   it (zakat), his "Zimma" (obligation) would not be discharged. In cases
>   other than those mentioned above it is permissible for a non-Hashimi
>   to give his Sadaqa, atonement, or Fidya of fast ( kaffara) or any
>   desirable charity to a Hashimi. Yes, if charity given to a Hashimi is
>   too little an amount of property and it is given with the intention of
>   repulsing calamity and evil, there is Ishkaal (objection) in its being
>   permissible.

(Hashimi mens Sayyiid)

---

**References and further info and reasoning:**

[Official website of Grand Ayatollah Sistani](http://sistani.org/index.php?p=855722&id=1358)

[Sadaqa For Syeds Is Haraam?](http://www.shiachat.com/forum/index.php?/topic/234973112-sadaqa-for-syeds-is-haraam/page__p__2008862__hl__sadaqa%20syed__fromsearch__1#entry2008862)

[Why Does It Matter If Someone Is Syed Or Not?](http://www.shiachat.com/forum/index.php?/topic/234934177-why-does-it-matter-if-someone-is-syed-or-not/)